# Spring MVC and Checkbox

Tags: java, spring-mvc, checkbox, data-binding, databinder

I read many posts, but I didn't find a solution.

I have an object called **Utente**.

**Utente** has a field called **autorizzazioniLista**

```
public class Utente{
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "utente", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Autorizzazioni> autorizzazioniLista;
    ...
}
```

**Autorizzazioni** has 3fields: **id**, **utente** and **autorizzazione**

```
public class Autorizzazioni {
    ...
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id; 

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Utente.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)    
    private Utente utente;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Autorizzazione.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Autorizzazione autorizzazione;
    ...
}
```

and this is **Autorizzazione**

```
public class Autorizzazione{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private int id;     

    @Column(name = "descrizione")
    private String descrizione;
}
```

I have a form with **Utente** as modelAttribute. In this form, the objects **Autorizzazioni** of the field **autorizzazioniLista** must be shown as checkbox; here start my problems.

This is the jsp page that shows the checkboxes:

```
  <form:checkboxes
          items="${utente.autorizzazioniLista}"
          path="autorizzazioniLista"
          itemValue="id" delimiter="<br><br>"
          itemLabel="autorizzazione.descrizione" />
```

When I submit the form and I retrieve the object Utente inside the controller, the objects  **Autorizzazioni** inside the field **autorizzazioniLista** have their relative fields **Utente** and **Autorizzazione** set to null, so I'm not able to save them on the DB.

The only field of the objects **Autorizzazioni** that is not null is **id**, since inside the tag `<form:checkboxes>` i set as `itemValue` the **id** of the objects **Autorizzazioni**

**NOTE**: of course I use a class that extends `PropertyEditorSupport`, in order to handle the objects **Autorizzazioni** inside the tag  `<form:checkboxes>`.

So, my final question is: before the object Utente is retrieved by the controller (the one called after the submit of the form), is there a way to manipulate the the fields of the objects **Autorizzazioni**?

Inside the controller (the one called after the submit of the form) I used `@Valid Utente`, so the fields of the object Utente must have no errors.

Comment: If you just trying to preprocess your model attribute take a look at HandlerInterceptorAdapter. Also you can skip @Valid annotation, process your object in controlled and then validate it yourself

Comment: Thank you @GeorgyGobozov.  I extended HandlerInterceptorAdapter; now i suppose I can retrieve my object "Utente" from the paramether "Object" of the method prehandle(), but i'm not understanding how.